# How to make Text inside Div Unselectable/uncopyable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a slider with simple combined JavaScript and CSS. I want to make the text inside the `<div>` unselectable. even if it's selected, I want it to be selected as one `<div>` or as an object, how do I achieve this?

If possible I don't want to use any jQuery library usage

Comment: jQuery is just a shortcut language for JavaScript. You can use pure JS. Also, post some code.

Comment: You should analyze why you're trying to do this.  You will not have prevented copying by anyone who knows about `view source` unless the content is generated dynamically.

Comment: @BobBrown or knows how to disable CSS...

Comment: @Nicolas yes it's pure JS, no jQuery library been used. Some answer already fill in without me post the code, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @BobBrown i just didn't want anyone to easily select it,and also the slider will be seen worse if it's text become selectable, and about it's content,yes they're generated dynamically

Comment: OK... the effect is cosmetic.  Good.  (Consider the HTML% `<input type=range` control.)

Comment: actually if it's really possible i want it to really seen as an image. so even in view-source/file_get_contents nobody could copy it easily

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use CSS for this. like:

```css
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

**[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/9qyyjy3L/)**

Comment: Text selected from fiddle, including spelling error:
`This text can not be seleced`
(I cheated and did what Ryan B suggested, namely I disabled the CSS.)

Comment: I apologize if that came across as snarky.  I wanted to make the point that there is very little one can do client-side that is real security.  CSS, transparent image overlays, etc. are effective against only those who are naive about how the web and web browsers work, a steadily diminishing part of the population.

Comment: @Bob Brown you are right. This will just prevent the innocent users to copy the text.

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="VALUE" readonly />
```

Comment: This doesn't at all answer the askers question.

Comment: He only want to block the copy no?

Comment: Two things; he asked about a div and not an input tag and adding the readonly doesn't prevent copying, it only prevents editing.